# Python 3: Local variable 'xyz' value is not used warning in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, warnings, local-variables

Here is my code snippet:

```
def my_function(x, y):
    ...
    xyz = 0
    try:
       do_something
       xyz = 1
    except (SomeException) as e:
       do_somethingelse
       if condition A happens:
           xyz = 2
       else:
           xyz = 0

    if xyz == 0:
       print("Case 1 happened")
    elif xyz == 1:
       print("Case 2 happened")
    else:
       print("Case 3 happened")

    return xyz
```

So although I am using `xyz` and even use it as return argument but I get a warning message in PyCharm that says: `Local variable 'xyz' value is not used`. What is the reason, and how can I resolve this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `xyz = 0` can be omitted, because in the next block of code, you are redefining its value.

It will either go all as expected and `xyz` will be set to `1`:

```py
try:
       do_something
       xyz = 1
```

or it will catch the exception and set it to either `2` or `0`:

```py
except (SomeException) as e:
    do_somethingelse
    if condition A happens:
       xyz = 2
    else:
       xyz = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What will happen if there is an exception, but it is not listed in the list of exceptions I am monitoring? For example, it is `SomeOtherException` instead of `SomeException`?

Comment: In that case, the execution would stop (because the `SomeOtherException` is not controlled in your code) and the `xyz` value would not be relevant

Comment: But I don't want the execution stop, how can I handle other exceptions that I have not listed?

Comment: You could add the uncontrolled exceptions either like ```except (SomeException, SomeOtherException) as e``` or adding more `except` clauses.